# When using WSL as toolchain for CLion, Cmake uses wrong path

Tags: cmake, clion, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have WSL which is configured to mount partitions at the root of the filesystem.

```
$cat /etc/wsl.conf
[automount]
root = /
options = "metadata"
```

That means my drives are accessed using paths which start from root e. g. /c /d etc...
CLion with WSL toolchain executes the command:

```
/usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/make -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /mnt/c/Users/dmytr/CLionProjects/untitled
bash: line 0: cd: /mnt/c/Users/dmytr/CLionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug: No such file or directory
CMake Error: The source directory "/mnt/c/Users/dmytr/CLionProjects/untitled" does not exist.
```

It is obvious that Cmake needs to be invoked where path-to-source starts with /c not /mnt/c.

How it is possible to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created an issue at JetBrains issue tracker - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-15459
Looks like there is known bug and it is already fixed in CLion 2019.1 EAP.

Comment: If this is a working solution for you, please accept your own answer to mark the question as resolved.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried, but I am getting an error "You can accept your own answer in 8 hours". Looks like something is wrong. It's more 24h has been passed.